# HTML5 "picture"-Tag doesn't work

Tags: css, html, image, responsive-design

i've got a problem with the HTML5 `picture`-element. I would like to show a smaller image for devices with a max-width of 600px. The other devices should get the big picture.

```
<picture alt="logo"> 
     <source src="img/b2b-logo-small.png" media="max-width: 600px">
     <source src="img/b2b-logo.png" >            
     <img class="logo" src="img/b2b-logo.png" /> <!-- Fallback -->
</picture>
```

Nothing happens if i reduce the width of the browser window because Chrome always shows the picture from the `img`-tag (Fallback). Why?

Comment: Mainly because the `picture` tag is not part of HTML5. It's a proposal. As far as I know, no browsers currently implement it.

Comment: Ah, ok. I just read it in this [article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/10/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/) Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The picture element [isn't supported in any browsers yet](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-picture-element/), it's still only a proposal.  It's going to hit that fallback whenever a browser doesn't support `<picture>`, so the only time it might not is if you have a [Chromium build that supports it](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/10/how-to-avoid-duplicate-downloads-in-responsive-images/) or something.

You can still use responsive images in the way that `<picture>` might implement it, if you don't have a problem using a JS polyfill. Scott Jehl, one of the members of the Responsive Images Community Group that's pushing `<picture>`, wrote [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill).

You'll have to write your code a little differently, instead of using the HTML tag, you'll use data attributes. An example from the picturefill docs:

```
<span data-picture data-alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
        <span data-src="small.jpg"></span>
        <span data-src="medium.jpg"     data-media="(min-width: 400px)"></span>
        <span data-src="large.jpg"      data-media="(min-width: 800px)"></span>
        <span data-src="extralarge.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 1000px)"></span>

        <!-- Fallback content for non-JS browsers. Same img src as the initial, unqualified source element. -->
        <noscript>
            <img src="external/imgs/small.jpg" alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
        </noscript>
    </span>
```

Comment: Thx. Now i use a little selfwrittten JS for this "problem": http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/HZrjj/

Answer (score 3):

As of November 2014, when Chrome 39 is out and it supports the `picture` tag since version 38, the problem in your code is that the `src="img/b2b-logo-small.png"`, as browsers don't support the `src` attribute in the `source` tag. It must be `srcset="img/b2b-logo-small.png"`.

See [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) for details.

Also checkout [picturePolyfill](https://verlok.github.io/picturePolyfill/), which is less complete but much faster then picturefill.

Comment: does it work now in chrome ? I can't find it works in latest chrome

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported as of yet, even by modern browsers because it doesn't belong to the official W3C HTML5 specs (it's not included in the list of [elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/elements.html)) and it's subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

You could write some media queries around each of the sizes that you are looking for and then using an ID on each size show and hide the images from the media query